# SSIS Removing results from one set when Id exist in another

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQLserver 2008r2 SSIS

I have two data sources from two different databases, within the data flow task i want to be able to remove the rows from source 1 where the ids exist in source 2 and output the remaining data from source 1

I'm finding it difficult to find the relevant Data Flow transform tasks.

If the data was in the same database then the in SQL it would simply be

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name
WHERE TableB.id IS null
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you tried the merge join and conditional split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a data flow task to pull all records from the source database to a staging table in the destination database.  Then use the statement in your question to get the data I needed.

Depending on the amount of data to be pulled / excluded you could also do it the opposite way.  Send the id's from the destination to a staging table in the source and then the query for the rows to pull in a similar way.

If you can not create staging tables in either the source or destination you should be able to do it all in SSIS transforms.  Maybe a lookup or as commented a merge join / conditional split.  I think the performance would be much better with the staging table approach.

Answer (score 0):

If your databases are located on the same server you can use the same syntax with adding the database name:

```
SELECT * FROM Database1.TableA AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Database2.TableB AS T2
ON T1.name = T2.name
WHERE T1.id IS null
```

If your databases are on different server then you should follow these steps:

- In a dataflow task you have to create an `OLEDB source` for `TableA`
- Add a Look up transformation control
- Choose `TableB` as Source of the Look Up object
- Link the `ID` column from `TableA` ON the `ID` column from `TableB`
- Choose any column from `TableB` as Output
- Configure Look Up object Error Output to ignore Failure (if no join value found it will return Null)
- Add a conditional split that filter Null values from the column marked as output in the Look up object
- link this output to your Destination

**OR**

You can create a Linked server in sql server and use a query like the following

```
SELECT * FROM Database1.TableA AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Server2.Database2.TableB AS T2
ON T1.name = T2.name
WHERE T1.id IS null
```

Read more about create [Linked Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx)

Comment: Thanks i did start off on the lookup transform, but got stuck because i can't define a date range parameter (which i can do in the OLEDB Source) which i need as the date range is key to whether the value is included or excluded.